# systemd-logind.service, get current settings?

Tags: systemd, logind

[The logind.conf page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#Description) says something about compiled defaults and multiple configurations files that has precedence rules. All those make it difficult for me to figure out what the current setting is. Is there a way to print the current settings that systemd-logind.service has currently loaded and is using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a way to show the currently loaded settings, but the next best thing is to use `systemd-analyze`:

```
systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/logind.conf
```

As you probably already read in the manual:

> Initially, the main configuration file in /etc/systemd/ contains commented out entries **showing the defaults** as a guide to the administrator.

So in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` you can see the defaults and if you don't get any entries with `systemd-analyze` that are not commented out, those are still your settings, because with `systemd-analyze` you get all config-files shown at once, so if you have an additional drop-in configuration-file under `/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/*.conf` it will also gets listed. E.g.:

```
[root@client systemd]# systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/logind.conf
# /etc/systemd/logind.conf
(...)
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
(...)
#SessionsMax=8192

# /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/logind.conf
[Login]
HandlePowerKey=ignore
```

So in this example only `HandlePowerKey=ignore` is set manually and overwrites the default `HandlePowerKey=poweroff`

If you only want to see the manually set non-defaults, just grep with an invert-match, e.g.

```
systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/logind.conf | grep -v "^#"
```

Changed settings get loaded by restarting the service

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

Comment: Since sytemd version 255 `grep` is no longer needed to get the relevant parts of the config by using `--tldr`. The **show interesting part** option `--tldr` is even better because the comments that show from which file the config is derived are printed.